# Trouble understanding the theorem that $\left |x_n-x\right |\leq Ca_n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(x_n)$ be a sequence of real numbers and let $x\in\mathbb{R}$. If $(a_n)$ is a sequence of positive real numbers with $\lim(a_n)=0$ and if for some constant $C>0$ and some $m\in\mathbb{N}$ we have $\left |x_n-x\right |\leq Ca_n$ for all $n\geq m$ then it follows that $\lim(x_n)=x$.

I am supposed to use this to show that for $c>1$ then $\lim(c^{\frac{1}{n}}$)=1
so we have that $c^{\frac{1}{n}}=1+d_n$ for $d_n>0$ and then by Bernoulli's Inequality we get $$c=(1+d_n)^n\geq 1+nd_n$$ Therefore $d_n\leq (c-1)/n$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ so we have that $$\left |c^{\frac{1}{n}}-1\right |=d_n\leq(c-1)\frac{1}{n}$$ Now I have to use the theorem above to show that it converges to 1 but I'm not sure how.

Comment: You've a a bit of an issue here.  You claim if $c>0$ then $c^{1/n}=1+d_n$ with $d_n>0$.  But if $0<c_n<1$, then $c^{1/n}<1$ which would mean $d_n<0$.

Comment: Whoops that's a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case,
$C$ in the theorem
is
$c-1$,
$a_n$ in the theorem
is $
\frac1{n}
$,
$x_n$ is
$c^{1/n}$,
and
$x$ is $1$.

Since
$a_n \to 0$,
$x_n \to x$.

Actually,
for this case,
you want $c > 1$,
not $c > 0$.
$1 > c > 0$ requires
a different argument.

Comment: Could you also explain this part of the proof to me: if $\varepsilon>0$ is given , then since $\lim(a_n)=0$, we know there exists $k=k(\varepsilon/C)$ such that $n\geq k$ implies $a_n=|a_n-0|<\frac{\varepsilon}{C}$ Therefore if both $n\geq k$ and $n\geq m$ then $|x_n-x|\leq Ca_n<C\frac{\varepsilon}{C}=\varepsilon$, I dont understand how they put $|x_n-x|$ in there.

Comment: $a_n$ gets and stays as small as you want. In particular, $a_n < \epsilon/C$ for all large enough $n$. Since $|x_n-x| < Ca_n$ for all large enough $n$, $|x_n-x| < Ca_n<\epsilon$ for all large enough $n$.

Answer (score 1):

You have, for $n\ge m$,
$$
x-Ca_n\le x_n\le x+Ca_n
$$
and by the comparison theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=x$. Removing the initial $m$ terms from a sequence doesn't change the limit.